# fixing chrome colors with respect to other browsers or vice versa

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, colors

I'm using a mix of gradients to achieve a special background effect on a html page:

```
// css, prefixed before use
background-image:
  radial-gradient(60% -5%, circle, rgba(75,230,195,0.6), transparent),
  radial-gradient(80% 80%, circle, rgba(255,255,0,0.9), transparent),
  radial-gradient(-5% 20%, circle, #f3774d, transparent);
```

Whilst developing in chrome I managed to get it to look exactly as I wanted, but when I checked the design on Safari and Firefox, the colours were off (and not by a little bit).

These screens show what I mean (top is Chrome, bottom is Safari/Firefox):

[image: google chrome]
[image: firefox and safari]

Is there any way to alleviate this problem? I'd like to have the gradients render the same
on every browser that supports them.

Is there a chrome specific hack I can use?
A flag I can set from css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a flaw in Firefox's and Safari's handling of the `transparent` keyword. They treat it the same as `rgba(0,0,0,0)`, so the colour of, for instance, the second run

```css
radial-gradient(80% 80%, circle, rgba(255,255,0,0.9), transparent),
```

goes from yellow to black. (Of course the black is fully transparent at the end, but halfway through the gradient it's more like dark grey.)

So what you should do is change `transparent` to the transparent version of the first colour, in this case

```css
radial-gradient(80% 80%, circle, rgba(255,255,0,0.9), rgba(255,255,0,0)),
```

I made a fiddle, where the top rectangle has `transparent` and the bottom one has the rgba values as mentioned, and as you can see, the bottom one has the same hues in all browsers.
http://jsfiddle.net/G9Lym/

[image]

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Sorry I didn't answer earlier, but this issue is something I only found out about later.